# Wrap Text Inside Rotated Div

Tags: css, rotatetransform

Any idea how can i make a text wrap inside a rotated div.
Text won't stay inside div after rotated..
Here's a screen of the idea...

[image: Div Rotated, and inside, Text rotated back to right degree]

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing that comes to my mind to solve this problem are CSS Regions (http://html.adobe.com/webstandards/cssregions/).

I've set up a small demo to show you how it works, here's the code:

```
div {
    -webkit-shape-inside: polygon(0% 50%, 50% 100%, 100% 50%, 50% 0%);
}
```

And here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sandro_paganotti/ABdgB/.

Unfortunately it works only on the latest Chrome, plus you have to manually enable 'Enable experimental WebKit feature' in your chrome://flags panel.

[image: here's a screenshot]

Comment: The feature is now called CSS Shapes. It was broken-off the main CSS Regions implementation.